# How to get response OK from POP3 server using ruby

Tags: ruby, pop3

For example, to get response 200 OK from "example.com", necessary:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

puts res.code       # => '200'
puts res.message    # => 'OK'
```

How to make similar for pop.gmail.com?

Comment: Not possible. pop.gmail.com is not a web service. It's an e-mail service for Gmail, and it uses the POP protocol, not HTTP.

Comment: But how do know that the server is ready to receive and transfer data? Just sometimes the connection is not the first time.

Comment: pop.gmail.com is not a HTTP server. It's not meant to be used by any web browser. Try and go to http://pop.gmail.com/ with your browser. It doesn't work. HTTP is a protocol for browsing the web, pop.gmail.com does not support this protocol. Comprende? :)

Comment: What exactly is it you are wanting to do? Maybe you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: Have a look at Ruby's POP support - http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/POP3.html

Comment: I have read this documentation. I thought that there was a similar technique for and for mail servers. @Casper thanks for answers.

Comment: @WandMaker thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
require "net/pop"

Net::POP3.enable_ssl(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) 
conn = Net::POP3.new("pop.gmail.com", 995)
conn.start(user_name, password)
conn.started?
```